# Extracting values from a PD dataframe using text strings from another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have two dataframes:

terms:

```
  Drug                   Treatment      
  Ibuprofen 800mg        Hip Replacement Surgery
  Tylenol   AM           Mild Dislocation
  Advil                  Fractured Tibia
  Quinone                Fever
  Penicillin 250mg       Histerectomy
                         Surgical removal of bunion
                         Therapy
                         Bunion
```

```
data:
    Records  Physician Visit 1                        Physician Visit 2
    604     Take 2 tablets of advil & 3 caps of pen   Stop pen but cont. with advil
            250mg twice daily                         as needed for the fracture                                
    210     2 tabs of Tyl 3x daily for 5 days         nan
    515     nan                                       surgery scheduled for 01/01/2017
    019     Call my office if bunion pain persist     nan
            after 3 days
```

My desire is to use the list of terms in the TERMS TABLE to extract more Drugs and Treatment info from a table with bulky physician notes. The output should look somewhat like this:

```
Records Visit1Drugs  Visit1Treatment  Visit2Drug   Visit2Treatment  Date
604     Advil,       nan              Advil        Fracture         nan
        Penicillin 
        250mg

210     Tylenol AM  nan               nan          nan              nan
515     nan         nan               nan          surgery          01/01/2017
019     nan         bunion            nan          nan              nan
```

I've made several attempt to make this a reality but I end up screwing up my code at every attempt. Presently, This is the only function code and it's only able to extract the entire record note/visit...which isn't what I hope to achieve

```
drugs = terms['Drug'].tolist()
drugs = [x for x in drugs if str(x) != 'nan']
drugs = list(set(drugs))
visit = data['physician visit 1'].tolist()
visit = [x for x in visit if str(x) != 'nan']
visit = list(set(visit))

visitDrugList = []
for i in range(0, len(drugs)):
    search = ".*" + drugs[i]
    visitDrug = re.compile(search)
    visitDrugs = list(filter(visitDrug.match, visit))
    i+=1
    if visitDrugs:
        #print (search)
        visitDrugList.append(visitDrugs)
visitDrugList
```

I'm able to get a list of drugs/visit and if modified, a list of treatments/visit. How do I make a new table (as shown above) with this extracted drug/treatment list?  I know that this isn't pythonic and there are more sophisticated ways to get this done - I'm looking for someone to look at my problem and point me in the right direction. Thank you all in advance!

Comment: What/where is the terms table you mentioned?

Comment: It's the first table with two columns (Drug and Treatment). Excuse my terrible editing :)